# IP not showing in /var/log/secure under rhost

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, fail2ban, scientific-linux

I'm trying to get Fail2Ban to block failed `sudo -i` commands, but the IP is not showing up in the logs.  For example when I log into the server with:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa USER@1.2.3.4
```

I then use:

```
sudo -i
```

to get to root.  When I check the log I then find this in `/var/log/secure`:

```
May 26 06:42:35 HOSTNAME sudo: pam_unix(sudo-i:auth): authentication failure; logname=USER uid=1320 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=USER rhost=  user=USER
```

As you can see there is no IP next to:

```
rhost=
```

I'm pretty sure if the IP was there it should be triggering this Fail2Ban rule in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf`:

```
^%(__prefix_line)sauthentication failure; logname=\S* uid=\S* euid=\S* tty=\S* ruser=\S* rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=.*)?\s*$
```

Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your linux distribution?

Comment: cat /etc/redhat-release
Scientific Linux release 7.2 (Nitrogen)